# Determining bounds for double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I must find the volume determined by $z \leq 6-x^2-y^2$ and $z \geq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

I know this question must seem very basic, but I just cannot seem to figure out the answer. I am also confused about how to tackle these sorts of problems in general, particularly setting up the integral. This is my attempt so far, although I know my answer is wrong:

Setting the two equations above equal to each other, we solve to find: $$x=\pm 2,y=0,z=2 \text{ OR } x=0,y=\pm 2, z=2$$ Now, using polar coordinates, we set $x=r\cos \theta,y=r\sin \theta$ and our bounds are now $z \leq 6-r^2$ and $z \geq r$. Then, we evaluate: $$\iint_D(6-x^2-y^2)dA=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2 r(6-r^2)drd\theta=\frac{56\pi}{3}$$ However, I know the answer should be $\frac{32\pi}{3}$. I assume I have made an error in the bounds for the $r$ term. What am I doing wrong, and what approach should I use in the future? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cylindrical coordinates, the region can be described as follows:

$$
E:=\{(r,\theta,z)\;|\; 0\le \theta \le 2\pi, 0\le r\le 2,r\le z \le 6-r^2 \}
$$

It follows that

$$
V=\iiint_E dV = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2\int_r^{6-r^2}rdzdrd\theta =\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^r(6-r^2-r) rdrd\theta=\frac{32\pi}{3}
$$

In general, you must first concentrate on the bounds of the integral. This is the hard part as  it cannot be done with a computer. To do this, it is a good idea to draw a picture of the region you are considering. Here, the nature of the functions invites us to describe it with cylindrical coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Your simultaneous solution is wrong.  If
$$z=6-x^2-y^2\ ,\quad z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ ,$$
then $z=2$ as you have found correcly (rejecting the solution $z=-3$).  However this means that $x,y$ could have any values satisfying
$$x^2+y^2=4\ ,$$
it doesn't have to be that one of them is $0$.

Using polar coordinates is then a good idea and you have $0\le r\le2$, $0\le\theta\le2\pi$.  But to find the volume, you have to integrate $z_{\rm max}-z_{\rm min}$, giving
$$V=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2 \bigl((6-r^2)-r\bigr)\,r\,dr\,d\theta\ .$$
I leave the evaluation up to you.